# Parameters in GET oauth in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, parameters, get

I am using the [Oauth-Ruby gem](https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby), and I am able to fetch particular resources by doing stuff like:

```
@photos = @access_token.get('/photos.xml')
```

I am wondering how I can pass parameters to that get.  I have tried doing:

```
@photos = @access_token.get('/photos.xml', :parameters => {:id => 1} )
```

But no luck. I can't find anything in the docs. Anyone knows?

Comment: Yeah, I want to use a Hash or some structure, because I have a huge big amount of parameters given with a hash.

Comment: Yeah, like "that works", or Yeah like "I'm not going to do that"?

Comment: That works but is not what I am looking for. I want to pass the parameters in some kind of structure instead of adding them to the URL.

Comment: It doesn't exist.  I suggest you write your own method of turning a predictable structure into a variable string.  If you look at https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby/blob/master/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb you can see it only takes two args: path, and headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is source of Oauth get method

```
   # File lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb, line 23
   def get(path, headers = {})
     request(:get, path, headers)
   end
```

As you can see, it does not support parameters. If you are on rails, there is a method .to_query on a hash

```
{a: "b", c: "d"}.to_query #=> "a=b&c=d"
```

If not, you can use something like addressable gem

```
Addressable::URI.form_encode({a: "b", c: "d"}) #=> "a=b&c=d"
```